# What is the earliest act of inferno where you can find the highest item level?

Tags: diablo-iii

From what I understand [there are 18](http://www.diablowiki.net/Chest_Armor)([or 16?](http://www.diablowiki.net/Gear_sets) conflicting information) tiers of items in Diablo 3. I assume that it might be 16 because that would equal a tier for each act/difficulty.
What is the earliest act in inferno where the highest item level can be dropped? Does tier affect item level in any way?

To clarify, [according to this page](http://www.diablowiki.com/Chest_Armor_List), item level is directly tied to item tiers.

Comment: FYI the 'tiers' mentioned are only in terms of visual appearance, not in terms of item quality or available affixes ([more info](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65854/how-do-the-armor-tiers-work)).

Comment: AFAIK the tier also affects the base stats of an item. of course with random stats, a single item from hell could be better than something dropped in inferno, but chances are higher that items from inferno will be better on average. I will clarify the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of version 1.0.3, the earlier Inferno act for tier 18 items to drop is act 1.

Previously, the earliest Inferno act for tier 18 items to drop was act 3.

([source 1](http://www.atomicmpc.com.au/Feature/299259,diablo-iii-interview---making-hardcore-hardcore-the-no-lan-issue-and-much-more.aspx) [source 2](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6262208/))